# Java SSL certificate import

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

When does one have to import the cert to the truststore ? Recently I tested an SSL connection to a server whose cert was signed by COMODO and the connection went through without having to import to truststore.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you have to import the certificate when its signing authority is not in the certificate store. Use

```
keytool  -v  -list  -keystore [/path/to/]cacerts
```

to see which ones are there. Keep in mind that Oracle's idea of a well-known signing authority is not necessarily the same as yours.

```
...
Alias name: comodoaaaca
Creation date: May 2, 2006
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
Issuer: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
...
```